# Is this proof of Carathéodory's theorem valid?

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

I'm working through some discrete geometry and am trying to get a more rigorous grasp of convex geometry. In particular, I would like to try proving this theorem *without* the use of Radon's Lemma, which is the classic route. Is this proof valid?

**Carathéodory's Theorem**: Given a point set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, any point in conv$(X)$ may be expressed as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points in $X$.

*Proof:* Let $X$ be as in the statement; if $|X| \leq d+1$, we are done, so assume that $|X| > d+1$, and assume for contradiction that $c \in$ conv$(X)$ may not be expressed as a convex combination of $d+1$ points in $X$. Since the convex hull are those points which may be expressed as convex combination, we know that $c$ is a convex combination of $q>d+1$ points, say $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{q} = Z \subseteq X$.

As the largest affine independent point set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is of size $d+1$, we know that $c$ may be expressed as an affine combination of $d+1$ points $D$ in $Z$, since the convex hull is a subset of the affine hull. That is:

$$c = \sum_{n=1}^{d+1} b_n x_{i_n}$$

where $\sum_{n=1}^{d+1} b_n = 1$ and the $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$. By the supposition, at least one of the $b_i$ must be negative; suppose that it is $b_1$. I claim we can find a convex set which includes $D$ and excludes $c$. Let $\lambda_1 = b_1/2$ and let:

$$\lambda_n = b_n + \frac{b_1}{2d}$$

It follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{d+1} \lambda_n = 1$. Let $l = \sum_{n=1}^{d+1} \lambda_n x_{i_n}$; I claim that the set described above is conv$(D \cup\{l\}) = K$. It is clear that $K \supseteq$ conv$(D)$, we must show that $c \notin K$. Indeed, assume for contradiction that $c \in K$, which implies $(c+l)/2$ is a convex combination of $K$. This means that $c+l = 2\sum_{n=1}^{d+1} \Lambda_n x_{i_n} + 2\Lambda_{d+2}l$, where $\sum \Lambda_i =1$ and $\Lambda_i \geqslant 0$. Then:

$$c + (1-2\Lambda_{d+2})l = 2\sum_{n=1}^{d+1} \Lambda_n x_{i_n}$$

which implies:

$$\frac{b_1 (3-2\Lambda_{d+2})}{2} = 2\Lambda_1$$

but by the convexity condition, $0 \leqslant \Lambda_{d+2} \leqslant 1$, and the supposition gives $b_1 < 0$, hence we have:

$$0 > \frac{b_1}{2} \geqslant \frac{b_1 (3-2\Lambda_{d+2})}{2} = 2\Lambda_1 \geqslant 0$$

which is a contradiction. Then $c \notin K$, where $K$ contains $D$. In other words, there is a small-enough convex set that includes *any* $D$ but not $c$; by definition $c$ is not in the convex hull of $D$. Any decomposition of $\text{conv}(X)$ into simplices shows that this is impossible ($c$ must be in *some* simplex), so we are done. $\square$

EDIT: For clarity on my main concern, I do not know if the last sentence is justified, or is in fact identical to Caratheodory's Theorem in a different wording. Am I begging the question?

Comment: should your $\lambda_n$ be $b_n+\frac{b_1}{2d}$?

Comment: @User Yes, it should! Thanks, that slipped past me, but it does not affect the rest of the computation, since $\lambda_1 = b_1/2$ regardless. I've corrected it, though.

Comment: I can't quite follow your argument. Couldn't you just take $K = \text{conv}(D)$? What do you mean by "there is a small-enough convex set that includes *any* $D$"? And yes, your final sentence is suspect. Carathérodory's theorem is exactly the statement that the set of simplices $\{\text{conv}(Y) : Y \subseteq X, |Y| \leq d+1\}$ cover $\text{conv}(X)$.

Comment: @DánielG. Thanks for the feedback, in particular your first question. I hadn't internalized that $x \in \text{conv}(D) \Rightarrow x$ is a convex combination of $d+1$ points, which is so obvious in retrospect. And thanks for the final point as well, I suspected that was the case, but I didn't know enough to be confident in it. If you want, you can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carathéodory's theorem can be rephrased as "given a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, the set of simplices $\{\text{conv}(Y) : Y \subseteq X, |Y| \leq d+1\}$ covers $\text{conv}(X)$", i.e. the union if these simplices is exactly $\text{conv}(X)$. So it seems, indeed, that you use the result that you are trying to prove.